# With default bean scope as singleton, isn't it going to be bad when concurrent calls occur?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have declared a Spring bean, which polls my email server every so and so seconds. If there is mail, it fetches it, and tries to extract any attached files in it. These files are then submitted to an Uploader which stores them safely. The uploader is also declared as a Spring bean. A third bean associates the email's sender with the file's filename and stores that in a DB.

It turned out that when a few people tried to send emails at the same time, a bunch of messy stuff happened. Records in the DB got wrong filenames. Some did not get filenames at all, etc.

I attributed the problem to the fact that beans are scoped to singleton by default. This means that a bunch of threads are probably messing up with one and the same instance at the same time. The question is how to solve this.

If I synchronize all the sensitive methods, then all threads will stack up and wait for each other, which is kind of against the whole idea of multithreading.

On the other hand, scoping the beans to "request" is going to create new instances of each of them, which is not really good either, if we speak about memory consumption, and thread scheduling

I am confused. What should I do?

Comment: You need to synchronize your methods, but more importantly you need to ensure that called methods aren't modifying instance data that other threads rely on. I'm only guessing since you haven't supplied your code, but it's probably much more than simple method synchronization. You seem to have a systemic problem of overwriting data before you're through with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with both @Bozho and @stivio answers.

The preferred options are to either pass store no state in a singleton scoped beans, and pass in a context object to the methods, or to use a prototype / request scoped beans that get created for every processing cycle. Synchronization can be usually avoided, by choosing one of these approaches, and you gain much more performance, while avoiding deadlocks. Just make sure you're not modifying any shared state, like static members.

There are pros and cons for each approach:

1. Singlton beans are act as a service-like class, which some may say are not a good Object-Oriented design.
2. Passing context to methods in a long chain of methods may make your code messy, if you're not careful.
3. Prototype beans may hold a lot of memory for longer than you intended, and may cause memory exhaustion. You need to be careful with the life cycle of these beans.
4. Prototype beans may make your design neater. Make sure you're not reusing beans by multiple threads though.

I tend to go with the service approach in most simple cases. You can also let these singleton beans create a processing object that can hold it's state for the computation. This is a solution that may serve you best for the more complexed scenarios.

**Edit:**
There are cases when you have a singleton bean depending on prototype scoped bean, and you want a new instance of the prototype bean for each method invocation. Spring supplies several solutions for that:

The first is using [Method Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction), as described in the Spring reference documentation. I don't really like this approach, as it forces your class to be abstract.

The second is to use a [ServiceLocatorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html), or your own factory class (which needs to be injected with the dependencies, and invoke a constructor). This approach works really well in most cases, and does not couple you to Spring.

There are cases when you also want the prototype beans to have runtime dependencies. A good friend of mine wrote a good post about this here: http://techo-ecco.com/blog/spring-prototype-scoped-beans-and-dependency-injection/.

Comment: I agree with you and upvoted, except for point 1. Singleton bean are not recommended because they make unit testing more difficult, and because they introduce magic dependencies, but we're talking about Java Singleton, those with private constructor and a static method to return an instance. Spring singletons don't have these problems.

Comment: @stivio when I wrote Singleton beans I meant spring beans in singleton scope, and not java classes implementing the singleton design pattern. I agree that the later is probably the most problematic pattern in the GoF book, but singleton spring beans are not hard to test at all - you can instantiate them, introduce interfaces, and mock dependencies. and test them like any other class.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I said: "Spring singletons don't have these problems." - that's why I don't agree with point 1, I'd agree if you were talking about GoF singletons.

Comment: I get your point now @stivio - will try to rephrase the sentence.

Comment: If I follow the abovementioned approach, I end up with a singleton Service which invokes an autowired, "prototype" scoped Manager class. This is not creating new instances on every request to the service though. On the other hand explicitly instantiating manager with getBean() is not a good practice either... more confused. I guess this makes a new separate question.

Comment: @user802232 you can use factories. I'll post an example later.

Comment: @user802232 please take a look at my edit, I think it should cover your questions.

Answer (score 12):

Singleton-scoped beans should not hold any state - that solves the problem usually. If you only pass data as method parameters, and don't assign it to fields, you will be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking abstractly: if you'e using Spring Integration, then you should build your code in terms of the messages themselves. Eg, all important state should be propagated with the messages. This makes it trivial to scale out by adding more spring Integration instances to handle the load. The only state (really) in Spring Integration is for components like the aggregator, which waits and collects messages that have a correllation. In this case, you can delegate to a backing store like MongoDB to handle the storage of these messages, and that is of course thread safe.

More generally, this is an example of a staged event driven architecture - components must statelessly (N(1) no matter how many messages) handle messages and then forward them on a channel for consumption by another component that does not know about the previous component from which the message came.

If you are encountering thread-safety issues using Spring Integration, you might be doing something a bit differently than intended and it might be worth revisiting your approach...

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise just declare your beans as request, don't worry about the memory consumption, the garbage collection will clear it up, as long there is enough memory it won't be a performance problem too.

Comment: My only problem is that I cannot make the MailManager's scope "request", because I am polling for mail using Spring Integration's service-activator, i.e. there is not really a web request. Can I still  somewhat mark the MailManager as "per-thread"?

Comment: You can also use Spring core's SimpleThreadScope (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html) which binds a bean to a thread-local

Answer (score 1):

Singletons should be stateful and thread-safe.

If a singleton is stateless, it's a degenerate case of being stateful, and thread-safe is trivially true. But then what's the point of being singleton? Just create a new one everytime someone requests.

If an instance is stateful and not thread-safe, then it must not be singleton; each thread should exclusively have a different instance.

Comment: I think stateful singletons are quite dangerous (they are effectively global variables). Why do you believe singletons should be stateful?